# Why does no one have the 'beta' badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, beta

I just got a new badge, so I checked out the [Badges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges) page, and started looking at which badges I and other users have earned.

No one has earned the 'beta' badge: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta

The requirements are:

> Actively participated in the private beta.

I know that a lot of people, myself included, participated in this part of the site.  Why does no one have the badge?

Comment: @oded I am not sure why Daniel removed the status completed, it was fixed.

Comment: @Kortuk - Ah. Didn't see the revisions. Just cleaning up old bug reports.

Comment: @Oded yeah, definitely what I thought happened, letting you know this is really resolved, not sure why daniel did, maybe his comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta badges have been awarded - thanks for the catch.

Comment: I think there is a mistake for this badge. Several people that earns it didn't participate in private beta, they participated when ED was ChipHacker. Beta phase stated in September, I think.

Comment: @DanielGrillo, I think being part of Chiphacker is still fair reason to give the beta badge, they took part in the alpha.

Comment: @Kortuk, for me no problem. Quae sunt Caesaris, Caesari.

Comment: @DanielGrillo, not everyone got the beta badge by being part of chiphacker either. I was with chiphacker in '09 and I did not get a beta badge, it may have worked well and given those that also had chiphacker accounts the badge.

Comment: @kortuk, I think that maybe we are a special case of Area51. They have to decide what's better. I don't wanna forget ChipHacker, but I'm wanna this badge too.

Comment: @danielGrillo, nothing to get worried about, I am not phased, just letting you know.

Comment: @Geoff, have you analyzed the problem that I put in my first comment?